# react native navigation on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

i have this code and i need to navigate to another component on button press

```
    const App = () => {
....}
export default App;
```

---this is the part where im trying to add navigation to the TouchableOpacity

```
<TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ViewDrafts")}
          >
            <Text style={styles.content}>View Drafts</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

error is `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`

any idea? how to fix that?

Comment: please mention what is navigation library you are using and how are the routes configured. This information is not enough.

Comment: sorry i wan trying to mention the whole code but they didn't let me post the question (too much code)...
i was using react-navigation @senthilbalaji

Comment: No need to be sorry, mention details that in question by editing and secondly you don't have to post the entire code, just show an example of your code will look like.  And most probably this issue is because you haven't wrapped your component within navigation module or `navigation` is not actually take from `props`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
navigation.navigate("ViewDrafts")
```

To this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("ViewDrafts")
```

If this is a functional component you need to include `navigation`, for example :

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

const Home = /*here*/({navigation}) =>(
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ViewDrafts")}
          >
            <Text style={styles.content}>View Drafts</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)

export default Home
```

Comment: it didn't work, its a problem conserning navigation it self i think..
maybe the implementation in all wrong in my code

Comment: You can update your answer with the implementation that is related to the issue